# Unable to run python script from bash scripts with string arguments

Tags: python, bash, slurm, hpc

I want to run it from a bash script but it is not accepting string input with spaces. It works with single words or hyphenated words. However the python command is correct and is working fine when I am running it directly from terminal.

**commands.txt**

```
python generate.py -p "Flower girl"
```

**jobFile.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

srun $(head -n $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID commands.txt | tail -n 1)

exit 0
```

**Running the bash script with :**

```
sbatch jobFile.sh
```

and getting the following error:
[error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMp1z.png)

I appreciate any suggestions :) Thank you!

Comment: I've never worked with `srun` and `sbatch`, but curious to know what is `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`  in your jobFile.sh?

Comment: just double quote any variable which may contain spaces

Comment: @ScottStensland like i did for "Flower girl" ? or do you mean something else?

Comment: @User123 I can also use : srun $(head -n 1 commands.txt). Doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Try escaping the quotes `python generate.py -p \"Flower girl\"` in `commands.txt`

Comment: @damienfrancois I tried that, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing contents of **jobFile.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

srun python generate.py -p "Flower girl"

exit 0
```

commands.txt is not required anymore.